# MySQL result data as link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not really a good web programmer but I wanted to try.

I want to make my result from database as a link for example
I want "click here" as click would redirect to a new page or something.
and I think the idea is like.. a href"this.webpage.com">click here /a
my code is.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'get_scrapy_scraped' );

function get_scrapy_scraped( $content )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_page( 'jobs' ) )
        return $content;

    $table_name    = $wpdb->prefix . "careers";
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );

    if ( ! $retrieve_data )
        return $content;

    $table = '<table><tr>
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>Location/Dept</th>
    <th>Complete Info</th>
    <th>Application Link<th>
    </tr>';

    foreach ( $retrieve_data as $row )
    {
        $table .= "<tr>
            <td>{$row->Job_Name}</td>
            <td>{$row->Job_Department}</td>
            // I want this Job_Link_Info and Job_Link_Apply to be links naming Click for Details and Click to Apply respectively
            <td>{$row->Job_Link_Info}</td>
            <td>{$row->Job_Link_Apply}</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    $table .= "</table>";

    return $table . $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $row->Job_Link_Info and $row->Job_Link_Apply are destinations for some sort you can just add an a tag and use that as the href attribute.

For example:

```
$table .= '<tr>
            <td>{' . $row->Job_Name . '}</td>
            <td>{' . $row->Job_Department . '}</td>
            // I want this Job_Link_Info and Job_Link_Apply to be links naming Click for Details and Click to Apply respectively
            <td><a href="{' . $row->Job_Link_Info . '}">Click for info</a></td>
            <td><a href="{' . $row->Job_Link_Apply . '}">Click to apply</a></td>
            </tr>';
```

Comment: I already tried that solution but gave me this instead...

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Well! That should do it! I owe it all!

Comment: Your welcome. Also one more thing. You should turn error reporting on so if there is a error in one of your scripts it will be displayed rather than getting a 500 error because they are not that helpful. Adding this should work: error_reporting(1); ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );

Comment: where can I put that in my code? and can you help me with this another question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176524/add-pagination-to-custom-wordpress-plugin