# error in paginating custom table in wordpress

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

As the title says, I have this code for a custom table with pagination. But my error is that it is not redirecting to paged number(always result of page 1). My code is:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'get_scrapy_scraped' );

function get_scrapy_scraped( $content )
{
include_once('paginator.class.php');

    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_page( 'jobs' ) ) //when jobs is read
        return $content;
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_careers";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$pages = new Paginator;
$pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];
$pages->mid_range = 9; // Number of pages to display. Must be odd and > 3
$pages->paginate();

echo $pages->display_pages();
echo "<span class=\"\">".$pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page()."</span>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_careers ORDER BY Job_Name ASC $pages->limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Job Name</th><th>Department/Location</th><th>Information</th><th>Apply Links</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row[3]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[2]</td></tr>\n";

}
echo "</table>";

echo $pages->display_pages();
echo "<p>Page: $pages->current_page of $pages->num_pages</p>\n";
echo "<p>SELECT * FROM table $pages->limit (retrieve records $pages->low-$pages->high from table - $pages->items_total item total / $pages->items_per_page items per page)";
}
```

and paginator.class.php is:

```
        <?php


    class Paginator{
        var $items_per_page;
        var $items_total;
        var $current_page;
        var $num_pages;
        var $mid_range;
        var $low;
        var $limit;
        var $return;
        var $default_ipp;
        var $querystring;
        var $ipp_array;

    function Paginator()
    {
        $this->current_page = 1;
        $this->mid_range = 7;
        $this->ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');
        $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
    }

    function paginate()
    {
        if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp=25;
        if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
        {
            $this->num_pages = 1;
//          $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
        }
        $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
        $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
        $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
        if($_GET)
        {
            $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            foreach($args as $arg)
            {
                $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
                if($keyval[0] != "pg" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
            }
        }

        if($_POST)
        {
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
            {
                if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
            }
        }
        if($this->num_pages > 10)
        {
            $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"?page=wp-retrieve-database&page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

            $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
            $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

            if($this->start_range <= 0)
            {
                $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
                $this->start_range = 1;
            }
            if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
            {
                $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
                $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
            }
            $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
                if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
                {
                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
                }
                if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            }
            $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
            $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
        }
        $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
        if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
        $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
    }
    function display_items_per_page()
    {
        $items = '';
        if(!isset($_GET[ipp])) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        foreach($this->ipp_array as $ipp_opt) $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'$this->querystring';return false\">$items</select>\n";
    }
    function display_jump_menu()
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring';return false\">$option</select>\n";
    }
    function display_pages()
    {
        return $this->return;
    }
}
```

which is from http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/
I hope someone can help! Tnx in advance

Comment: You need to add a limit and offset to the query based on the current page and the amount of rows you want to show. For example if you are on page 1 and each page has 10 records you will need to add LIMIT 10 to the end of the query and if you are on page two you will need to add OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 because you want to skip the first 10 rows that were shown on page 10 and show the following 10. There are plenty of pagination tutorials you can look at for example http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: I fixed the error by removing jobs and make it as
href=\"?page . the only problem now is that I always stick to result page 1 of no_table.